# Select statement to fiind group without values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `XXX`

```
X    Y
---- -----------
A    1
A    2
A    3
B    1
B    2
C    1
C    2
C    3
```

I'm trying to find distinct values from column `X` which don't have a value of 3 in column `Y`

Based if the sample data, I should receive one value:

```
B
```

Comment: but how? there're 2 A, 2 C and 2 B records where Y <> 3
query `select distinct X from XXX where Y != 3` returns A,B,C

Comment: I think he wants to say if there is any 3 exclude that value from col X. So only B and C will remain.

Comment: Why is not `C` included in the output?

Comment: something is wrong in description of task... B and C have same Y-values and a query returns both of them

Comment: @felix.  Because there is a row with C, which has a value 3 in Y.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `COUNT` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT X
FROM XXX
GROUP BY X
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Y = 3 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/579491)</kbd>

Comment: This will not produce B,C

Comment: @AnkitBajpai See for yourself. Check the online demo

Comment: I extremely apologize for my mistake. I didn't check you having cond. I am extremely sorry.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai No problem.

Comment: this will return both B and C, but topic starter asked for B only

Comment: Your data set doesn't match the ops.  Hence B&C are returned.  I would infer that the op changed the dataset since your answer.

Comment: @EvilTeach you're correct. I'll update my sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a not in and subselect

```
 select distinct x from XXX 
 where  x not  in (
              select x from XXX
              where  Y=3 )
```

Comment: this will return both B and C, but topic starter asked for B only

Comment: @are ... but looking at the data B and C have same content so how is possible with information produced  by OP select on B.. .. (or the sample proived  is wrong or there others condition for get only but) stand the actula sample  my answer  should be correct

Answer (score 0):

Start with the whole set.

Subtract out the parts you don't want.

```
WITH
BASE AS
(
    SELECT 'A' x,    1 y FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' x,    2 y FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' x,    3 y FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' x,    1 y FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' x,    2 y FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C' x,    1 y FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C' x,    2 y FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C' x,    3 y FROM DUAL
)

SELECT DISTINCT X
FROM BASE

MINUS

SELECT X
FROM BASE
WHERE Y = 3
;
```